# .save() function not working even after using .markModified()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am taking a course in coursera for full stack development. While integrating REST API with express and mongo, .save() in my post function is not working. I've been at it for a couple of days now.

I tried using .markModified(), even that did not work. Lastly, I have attached the snippet of .post() here. It is only this post function that is not working.

```js
.post((req, res, next) => {
    Dishes.findById(req.params.dishId)
    .then((dish)=>{

        if (dish != null){
            
            dish.comments.push(req.body);
            console.log(dish);
            // dish.update({_id:req.params.dishId}, {$push: {comments: req.body}})
            dish.markModified('comments');
            dish.save()
           .then((dish) => {
                
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/ json');
                res.json(dish);
            }, (err) => next(err));

        }
        else{   
            err = new Error("Dish " + req.params.dishId + " not found.")
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

This is the schema:

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        max: 5,
        min: 1,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

const dishSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        default: ' '
    },
    price: {
        type: Currency,
        required: true,
        min: 0
    },
    featured: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false
    },

    comments: [ commentSchema ]
},

    {
        timestamps: true    
    }
);

var Dishes = mongoose.model('Dish', dishSchema);
```

This is the error i got:

```
ReferenceError: /path/to/views/error.jade:4

 2| 
    3| block content
  > 4|   h1= message
    5|   h2= error.status
    6|   pre #{error.stack}
    7| 

title is not defined
    at eval (eval at exports.compile (/path/to/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:171:8), <anonymous>:18:58)
    at /path/to/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:172:35
    at Object.exports.render (/path/to/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:206:14)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/path/to/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:233:13)
    at View.render (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /path/to/app.js:51:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/path/to/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
```

Anybody???

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(err)` below calling the `next(err)` for the `dish.save()` function. Like `dish.save().then(
  (dish) => {
    // handling success
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
);`

Comment: Thank you very much @Vishnu for your concern. I got it solved by putting `{usePushEach: true}` option in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

turns out putting `{usePushEach: true}` in the Schema Definition resolves the issue.